# How can I write a recursive polymorphic function with Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I can write a simple recursive polymorphic function:

```
object simpleRec extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](identity)
  implicit def caseList[A, B](implicit ev: simpleRec.Case.Aux[A, B]) =
    at[List[A]](_.headOption.map(simpleRec))
}
```

This seems to largely do what I want; however, I seem to be getting a nonsensical result type:

```
scala> simpleRec(List.empty[List[Int]])
res3: Option[B] = None

scala> simpleRec(List(List(1)))
res4: Option[B] = Some(Some(1))
```

How can I make this give me values of `Option[Option[Int]]` rather than `Option[B]`? I expect I'm making some silly mistake here, but can't work out what it is.

Comment: This is a neat question. My reflexive answer was "just use `Case[A]`", which will give you the correct inferred type, but that does weird stuff in e.g. `simpleRec(List(List(1))): Option[Option[Int]]`.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably was a bug, the following code works as expected:

```
object simpleRec extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](identity)
  implicit def caseList[A](implicit ev: simpleRec.Case[A]) =
    at[List[A]](_.headOption.map(simpleRec))
}
```

Using `shapeless_2.11-2.0.0`